# Use if not exists in where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm getting `Incorrect syntax near 'ctm'` 
Following is the query...

```
SELECT * FROM fit.dbo.CityTemplate ctm WHERE
NOT EXISTS (ctm.TemplateCode in (SELECT pit.TourCode
FROM sales97..City cy
Inner join sales97.dbo.Region rg ON rg.Region_Code = cy.Region_Code
Inner join presets.dbo.ProductItinerary pit ON pit.ProductCode =             
rg.Region_Code AND pit.ProductType = 'REGN'
WHERE isnull(pit.FrzInd,0) = 0  and isnull(rg.FrzInd,0) = 0  and     
isnull(rg.Showonwebind,0) = 1 
and (cy.Region_Code in ( SELECT * FROM Sales97.dbo.SplitString(@Where, ','))      
or cy.City_code = replace(replace(isnull(@Where,''),',',''),'cy_',''))))
OR (SELECT pit.TourCode FROM Sales97..Region rg
Inner join presets.dbo.ProductItinerary pit ON pit.ProductCode = 
rg.Region_Code AND pit.ProductType = 'REGN'
WHERE rg.Region_Code in ( SELECT * FROM Sales97.dbo.SplitString(@Where, 
',')))
```

If Query 1 i.e `'sales97..City` does not return any row then I have to execute Query2 i.e `Sales97..Region`.

Comment: Your first line is wrong. write syntax like 
`IF NOT EXISTS(ctm...)
BEGIN
SELECT * FROM fit.dbo.CityTemplate ctm where (Select count(*) as count ... WHERE count != 0)
END
ELSE
BEGIN
...
END
`

Comment: SELECT -query1- WHERE NOT EXISTS -query2-

Comment: Please add your DBMS

Comment: What are you trying to do??? Show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text, not images.

Comment: There is no `IF` or `END` in (standard) SQL

Answer (score 1):

This is the SQL you posted but a bit formatted:

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    fit.dbo.CityTemplate ctm 
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS (
        ctm.TemplateCode in (
            SELECT 
                pit.TourCode
            FROM 
                sales97..City cy
                Inner join sales97.dbo.Region rg ON rg.Region_Code = cy.Region_Code
                Inner join presets.dbo.ProductItinerary pit ON 
                    pit.ProductCode = rg.Region_Code AND 
                    pit.ProductType = 'REGN'
            WHERE 
                isnull(pit.FrzInd,0) = 0 and 
                isnull(rg.FrzInd,0) = 0  and     
                isnull(rg.Showonwebind,0) = 1 and 
                (
                    cy.Region_Code in (
                        SELECT 
                            * 
                        FROM 
                            Sales97.dbo.SplitString(@Where, ',')) or 
                    cy.City_code = replace(replace(isnull(@Where,''),',',''),'cy_','')))) OR 
    (
        SELECT 
            pit.TourCode 
        FROM 
            Sales97..Region rg
            Inner join presets.dbo.ProductItinerary pit ON 
                pit.ProductCode = rg.Region_Code AND 
                pit.ProductType = 'REGN'
        WHERE 
            rg.Region_Code in (SELECT * FROM Sales97.dbo.SplitString(@Where, ',')))
```

Several problems here:

- You are using `NOT EXISTS` without linking your `ctm` table with the correlated query (I'm assuming you want it related). So in any place inside the subquery you want to filter by `ctm.TemplateCode`.

  ```
  SELECT 
      pit.TourCode
  FROM 
      sales97..City cy
      Inner join sales97.dbo.Region rg ON rg.Region_Code = cy.Region_Code
      Inner join presets.dbo.ProductItinerary pit ON 
          pit.ProductCode = rg.Region_Code AND 
          pit.ProductType = 'REGN'
  WHERE

      pit.TourCode = ctm.TemplateCode AND -- Here

      isnull(pit.FrzInd,0) = 0 and 
      isnull(rg.FrzInd,0) = 0  and     
      isnull(rg.Showonwebind,0) = 1 and 
      (
          cy.Region_Code in (
              SELECT 
                  * 
              FROM 
                  Sales97.dbo.SplitString(@Where, ',')) or 
          cy.City_code = replace(replace(isnull(@Where,''),',',''),'cy_','')))
  ```
- There is a syntax error at the start of the `NOT EXISTS`. This operator needs a result set (aka `SELECT`), you can't use `ctm.TemplateCode IN (...)`. This error is repeated on the 2nd subquery also. The correct way is like the following:

  ```
  SELECT 
      * 
  FROM 
      fit.dbo.CityTemplate ctm 
  WHERE
      NOT EXISTS (
          SELECT 
              ...
          FROM 
              SomeTable T
          WHERE
              T.Field = ctm.Field AND /*Link outmost table with inner tables so it's correlated!*/
              ...)
  ```

Please try this fixed SQL, although I'm assuming a few things you might need to check if it suits what you are looking for with this query:

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    fit.dbo.CityTemplate ctm 
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 
            pit.TourCode
        FROM 
            sales97..City cy
            Inner join sales97.dbo.Region rg ON rg.Region_Code = cy.Region_Code
            Inner join presets.dbo.ProductItinerary pit ON 
                pit.ProductCode = rg.Region_Code AND 
                pit.ProductType = 'REGN'
        WHERE
            ctm.TemplateCode = pit.TourCode AND -- Link ctm to pit
            isnull(pit.FrzInd,0) = 0 and 
            isnull(rg.FrzInd,0) = 0  and     
            isnull(rg.Showonwebind,0) = 1 and 
            (
                cy.Region_Code in (
                    SELECT 
                        * 
                    FROM 
                        Sales97.dbo.SplitString(@Where, ',')) or 
                cy.City_code = replace(replace(isnull(@Where,''),',',''),'cy_',''))) OR 

    NOT EXISTS ( -- Repeat the NOT EXISTS operator
        SELECT 
            pit.TourCode 
        FROM 
            Sales97..Region rg
            Inner join presets.dbo.ProductItinerary pit ON 
                pit.ProductCode = rg.Region_Code AND 
                pit.ProductType = 'REGN'
        WHERE
            ctm.TemplateCode = pit.TourCode AND  -- Link ctm to pit
            rg.Region_Code in (SELECT * FROM Sales97.dbo.SplitString(@Where, ',')))
```